# I need "getxCoor()" but it shows me an error and have me writing "getyCoor()" (JAVA)

Tags: java

I am currently coding the game Snake in java, I have everything done, but here's my problem:
I have coded everything about the apple of Snake but there's a problem when i try to program that if the snake touches the apple, then it grows up.

> What i have

```
for(int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
                if(xCoor == apples.get(i).getyCoor() && yCoor == apples.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                    size = size + 3;
                    apples.remove(i);
                    i++;
                    score++;
                }
            }
```

> What i need to have

```
for(int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
                if(xCoor == apples.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == apples.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                    size = size + 3;
                    apples.remove(i);
                    i++;
                    score++;
                }
            }
```

I can't use the "getxCoor" because it shows me an error on Eclipse "*the method is undefined for the type Apple*"
I appreciate any help, thank you ! :)

Comment: can you share the class Apple? getter for xCoor may not be implemented.

Comment: Does the element type under apples list have the `getyCoor`?

Comment: @itwasntme `for(int i = 0 ; i < snake.size(); i++) {
     if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor == snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
      if(i !=snake.size()- 1) {
       stop();
      }
     }
    }`

Comment: @Asel`public class Apple {

 private int xCoor, yCoor, width, height;
 
 public Apple(int xCoor, int yCoor, int tilesize) {
  this.xCoor = xCoor;
  this.yCoor = yCoor;
  width = tilesize;
  height = tilesize;
 }
 
 
 
 public void draw(Graphics g) {
  
  g.setColor(Color.red);
  g.fillOval(xCoor * width, yCoor * height, width, height);
  
 }

 public int getyCoor() {
  return yCoor;
 }

 public void setyCoor(int yCoor) {
  this.yCoor = yCoor;
 }

 public int getWidth() {
  return width;
 }

 public void setWidth(int width) {
  this.width = width;
 }

}`

Comment: oh boy,Um gonna update your question and take a look at it.

Comment: @AZZ Add getters and setters for xCoor.

Comment: @Asel The getters and setters are already set in the apple class. Or do you mean in the class that contains my problem ?

Comment: @Asel My god I'm really stupid i forgot to add the getters and setters for xCoor, thank you a lot, have a wonderful day !